# What filament would be best for Creality's Ender 3 v2?

Tags: creality-ender-3, filament, filament-choice, creality

What would the best filament for an Ender 3 V2 be? I don't mind about the look but I would like for you to be able to bridge with it and for it to be reasonably cheap. If possible could you give several different options at different prices, different qualities and could you describe which website/company you can get it from.

Comment: Shopping questions like this are out of scope for the site. If you could be more specific about what properties you want, you could reformulate this question into one about what materials have the desired properties and make it in-scope.

Comment: Really, there are only a few materials that print well on a stock Ender 3 (PLA, PVB, and to a lesser extent PETG, ASA, ABS, and TPU) and they each have specific reasons you might choose them. Exotic materials beyond that list mostly require high-temperature capabilities and/or heated chamber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry - no one here can tell you to buy brand X from website Y.

However there are an enormous number of options and eliminating some broad categories can help.

1. Presuming your printer is stock, it has a brass nozzle, and therefore anything "reinforced" or abrasive is not feasible.  That excludes carbon fibre or nylon-reinforced filaments.
2. ABS is probably unprintable, unless you've added a heated enclosure
3. TPU might work, but it has properties that suit certain kinds of jobs, like flexible phone cases.  If you're not printing those things, TPU is wasted.
4. PETG is also a maybe - I have no experience with it.
5. PLA is the best for printing on an entry-level printer like an ender3.

You can eliminate all 2.85mm and 3mm filament, because your stock nozzle is a 1.75mm

I've personally not tried TPU or PETG on my ender3v2, mostly because committing to a whole roll is an expense I can't justify.

If I were you I'd ask anyone locally who prints, "where do you get good filament?" and use that as a starting point.  Ask your local library if they have a 3d printing service (this is astonishingly common) and where they source filament.

Some people only use the cheapest filament available, others have preferred brands, and others use only premium supplies.  Figure out what your personality is.

Going cheap is reasonable if you're only toying about.  If this printer is doing real work for people, consider stepping up to something better - cost of failed prints will outweigh the cost of better filament as your skills improve.

I would suggest exploring different styles of PLA, like the metallic-look or Silk mixes.  You can also get great effects from Rainbow PLA, which mean you have to have fewer colours in stock.  Lastly PLA+ mixtures exist, which are improvements on plain PLA.

Comment: Notes on printing PETG  https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10288/how-to-work-with-petg-settings-caveats-etc